# How can I get exceptions from django-rest in my vue.js method?

Tags: django, vue.js, django-rest-framework

I'm using django-rest-passwordreset for forgotten password recovery. In my Vue.js I have a method to set a new password. It works, but I need to get exceptions if a password is too short or too common etc...
Here is my vue.js set_password:

```
methods: {
    set_password() {
        axios.post('/app/reset-password/confirm/', {'password': this.password, 'token': this.token})
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response)
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error)
        })
    }
},
```

If I send POST request to `http://localhost:8000/app/reset-password/confirm/` using RestMan to raise exceptions on django server, for example: a short password I'm getting:

```
{
    "password": [
        "This password is too short. It must contain at least 8 characters.",
        "This password is too common."
    ]
}
```

but in my vue.js set_password() I really cannot get these exceptions. In browser console I'm getting:

```
POST http://localhost:8000/app/reset-password/confirm/ 400 (Bad Request)
Error: Request failed with status code 400
    at createError (build.js:15685)
    at settle (build.js:27186)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (build.js:15559)
```

If I send a good password(not short, etc...) I will 'response' in my browser console:

```
{data: {…}, status: 200, statusText: "OK", headers: {…}, config: {…}, …}
```

But How can I get exceptions from my django server?

Answer (score 1):

In your `vue.js`, if you log `error.response.data` will provide you the complete error.

Comment: It's not going to .catch at all. I'm doing something like that:
.then(response => {
    console.log(response, ' < from .THEN')
})
.catch(error => {
    console.log(error => {
    console.log(error.response.data)
})

Comment: I'm getting only :
POST http://localhost:8000/app/reset-password/confirm/ 400 (Bad Request)
Error: Request failed with status code 400
    at createError (build.js:15667)
    at settle (build.js:27162)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (build.js:15541) "< from .THEN"